# HTML not rendering on Salesforce using $sce and ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs, salesforce

I am using Salesforce as the back end and my users can get some notifications that could contain an  tag with a link to somewhere. This being said I have used $sce in the controller to do a function like this:

```
vm.to_trusted = to_trusted;
function to_trusted(html_code) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
}
```

In the front end I am using it as such:

```
<p ng-bind-html="vm.to_trusted(message.body)"></p>
```

An example of the returned message.body is

```
<a href="/#/app/profile">Click Here to Fill out your Profile</a>. It will allow you
```

On localhost this works awesome with the link being shown and not the  tag. On Salesforce, this is not the case with the above being shown instead. Any ideas as to why this is not working?

UPDATE:

Yes I do have ngSanitize included :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Salesforce `@dispatch` requests serialize text in an odd manner.

If the content of a Salesforce string is: `'<a href="">Things</a>'` you will see in Angular that you've received: `&lt;a href=&quot;$quot;&gt;Things&lt;a&gt;`

The solution I've found is, in your controller:

```
function to_trusted(html_code) {
  // Cause the &ltg; etc become '<'
  return $('<textarea />').html(html_code).text();
}
```

Because Salesforce.